# Is there a mocking framework that works with the .NET Client Profile?

Tags: .net, mocking, .net-client-profile

I have a somewhat exotic use case for a mocking framework. I would like to generate stub objects to be used by the WinForms designer in my client application. The point is to enable dependency injection using a static service locator, while retaining drag-and-drop designer functionality.

Unfortunately, all of the mocking frameworks I've tried require me to switch my application to use the full .NET framework profile.

I'm wondering if there's any that work with the Client Profile. Something tells me that there might not be any - is there any inherent limitation to the Client Profile that makes it impossible to generate classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I think this will become irrelevant soon since .NET 4.5 no longer divides between Client and Full profiles.